# json standards for structure of responses

Tags: javascript, json, standards

I'm trying to decide on a standard for json responses for my applications going forwards.

So I'm thinking something along the lines of

Fake Json
    {
    Message:"hello, this is a reponse",
    action: 0 or 1, or "Good" or "bad",
    statusCode: 234,
    }

I'm wondering if there is a good standard for this already, and also how I can keep my standards in sync between my front and back end?

Is there a clever way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806386/standard-json-api-response-format

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a structure similar to this:

```
{ status: ("ok", "error" or "redirect"), message: "some message goes here.", fields: "field selectors goes here in case some highlighting is needed", url: "url to open or redirect to if needed" }
```

- The `status` property is the key to tell what to do next;
- The `message` can be used to show a popup message or an inline message, etc. Can also be a list of messages separated by a '|' character to split;
- The `field` property is used to select (with jQuery or other JS library) the fields or other objects that need an action (think of this for field validation);
- The `url` property is used to change the page, open a popup or post something back, depending on your needs.