# "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I have the following **route**

```
namespace :dashboard do
  get   '/courses/:id/edit'                     => 'courses#edit',                :as => :edit_course
  put   'courses/:id/update'                    => 'courses#update'
end
```

and this **form**

```
  = form_tag dashboard_edit_course_url( @course), :method => 'post', :multipart => true do
    ...
```

the **action** being:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://localhost:3000/dashboard/courses/54633b9fc14ddd104c004de3/edit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

But when I submit the form I get this error:

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
>
> You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

I don't understand why? Could somebody explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way to handle this. In your routes write:

```
namespace :dashboard
  resources :courses, only: [:edit, :update]
end
```

And in your view write:

```
= form_tag [:dashboard, @course], multipart: true do |f|
```

Then you will use rails defaults.

Comment: Changing the routes might require a restart of your rails server. Otherwise, how does the form look in html now?

Comment: nice improvement to the routes!

Answer (score 1):

Your form states to use `post`, but you don't have a `post route` configured.

The rails way to do this is to submit the form to the update path via `put`, since you are [updating a record](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19504523/2235594):

```
= form_tag dashboard_update_course_path( @course), :method => 'put', :multipart => true do
```

Also, you probably want to [use `path` instead of `url`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11939978/2235594).

Then just name the `update route`:

```
namespace :dashboard do
  get   '/courses/:id/edit' => 'courses#edit', :as => :edit_course
  put   '/courses/:id/update' => 'courses#update', :as => :update_course
end
```

Comment: I try to change the form to method => 'put' but it always render with post. Do you know why???

Comment: Depending on what browser you use, it [may not be supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers). You could also try this with `post`. This will work, but it's not as correct as `put`.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter is where the form submission should go (update).

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag