# Most Efficient Form Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm looking for the most efficient method for form validation and I'm wondering if my current implantation is not only possible but sustainable when dynamically scaling.  Take a look:

(Warning: Ignore silly HTML class names)

```
// --------- Validate Required Fields ----------
$('.valid8-form').submit(function() {
  // Array to Store Errors
  $('.valid8-errors').html('');
  var formValidationErrors = [];

  if ($('.valid8-requried').val() === '' || $('.valid8-requried').val() === null) {
    formValidationErrors.push('The ' + $('.valid8-requried').name + ' field is required!');
}

  // Place Errors In List on DOM
  for (var i = 0; i < formValidationErrors.length; i++) {
    $('<li>', {
      text: formValidationErrors[i]
    }).appendTo($('.valid8-errors'));
  }
});
```

Is there a way to do a forEach blank field in input add error string to the array?  Right now, it only throws a string in the array for the first blank field it hits.

Comment: all validations on client side aren't safe, use server side validation.

Comment: Use both, IMHO @Pedro Lobito.  Client side validation can be performed using the same dataset as server side and provide a good user experience lacking network lag for asynchronous validation requests.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you will want to consider for future scalability is the ease of maintaining your validation rule set and your form design.  This is a good topic because there is no standard way to do this, but lots of ideas and the quest for the "best" is a good one.

I've done some work where I use JSON to define my form and then write a function to render the form for me.  This consolidates information about the form, including validation rules, to an easily read and maintained object definition that can be loaded from a datasource if you want.

You can see an example of what I'm refering to in my question seeking a standard here: [Is there an accepted or emerging JSON form and field definition format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159693/is-there-an-accepted-or-emerging-json-form-and-field-definition-format)

See the validation property on the form definition given there.

So, a good question to ask is: are we looking for script performance efficiency or are we looking for total ownership efficiency, where changes are easy to make?  I think the former is less important if you are using a framework like jquery to handle your interrogations of the DOM.  Efficiency has been attended to in that matter, for the most part.  That leaves the question: what's the easiest way to maintain this when it grows far beyond our expectations?  I think the JSON approach is a good one worth trying out.

As for script efficiency, I can tell you from benchmarking that your for(var i=0... is far faster than for(var obj in objs), so in that regard, you have achieved script efficiency.

One thing you could do to improve your efficiency is cache your DOM references.

```
var verrors = $('.valid8-errors');
$('.valid8-form').submit(function() {
  // Array to Store Errors
  verrors.html('');
  var vrequired = $('.valid8-required');
  var formValidationErrors = [];

  if (vrequired.val() === '' || vrequired.val() ===      null) {
    formValidationErrors.push('The ' + vrequired.name + ' field     is required!');
}

  // Place Errors In List on DOM
  for (var i = 0; i < formValidationErrors.length; i++) {
    $('<li>', {
      text: formValidationErrors[i]
    }).appendTo(verrors);
  }
});
```

This prevents multiple queries of the DOM to find the same object and should give a small performance boost, more notably with older browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Efficiency on the script side is my number one priority, but finding a happy medium would be nice.

Comment: Updated my answer with some small tips towards that end.