# Polymer expression

Tags: php, json, expression, polymer

I'm trying to use the [Polymer expressions](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html) to show certain things.

I have a `.php` file that prints out a json_encoded array of for example names. Now there's 3 possibilities the way I see it:

1. The list of names gets returned properly
2. There are no names found in a database, so `null` or something is printed
3. An error occured in the php file

So depending on what gets returned, I'd like to display the correcy message.

This can be done using [`<template if="{{conditionalValue}}">`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#conditional-templates). This is what I have:

```
<template if="{{people != null}}">
    <template repeat="{{person in people}}">
        <name-card name="{{person.name}}">
        </album-card>
    </template>
</template>

<template if="{{people == null}}">
    <div>There are no people listed.</div>
</template>
```

This doesn't seem to work. When the `.php` file returns a list, the top templates both get executed and I get a whole list of `<name-card>` elements. However, when in the php file I do `echo json_encode(null)` for testing measures, nothing displays at all. So I must be doing something wrong with my conditionalValue. How do I test whether this is an array with elements in it?

Also, is there a way to test for non-json content, in case of an error on the php script?

Comment: I am confused what you actually see in the browser. Does the HTML render correctly and the JSON for people just hasn't returned in time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for example the developer console of Chrome (or some other tool) to see what the call to your PHP script actually returns (because *"`null` or something"* is a bit vague.)

Then at some point log the contents of the `people` property to see whats actually in it. I doubt that this property is really `null`. Presumably its something like `""` or `[]` (or even `"null"`).

If `people` is indeed null, then your code works fine. One can verify this with a small test element that only contains the two templates and sets the `people` property directly in the `created()` function.

In all other cases it depends. If the empty case is an empty array, you could write for example:

```
<template if="{{people.length > 0}}">
```

and

```
<template if="{{people.length == 0}}">
```

To your question regarding the non-json response error: it depends again. If you parse the JSON content with `JSON.parse()` yourself, then it will throw an exception in case of an error. If you use `core-ajax`, its current implementation catches the error, logs a warning and returns the XHR response text. So you may want to extend this element and overwrite the `jsonHandler()` function. Or use `core-xhr` and implement the JSON parsing yourself.

The best way to handle errors is to always return a valid JSON response (with properties like `"error"` or `"message"`) and use HTTP status codes. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806386/standard-json-api-response-format) for further reading.

Comment: `people.length > 0` did the trick! I said _`null` or something_ because I could easily change the response of the script. I'm currently using `core-ajax`, so I guess I'll use the `core-error` method to set `people` to -1 or so and check that first. Thanks for all your help (again!). Small question though - when the php file returns something non-JSON `core-ajax` catches an exception, but I'm not sure how to catch this.

Comment: Isn't it `<template is="dom-if" if="{{people.length == 0}}">` ?