# Is there any statndard pattern for returning the JSON response

Tags: java, json

I am using the following design for JSON response

```
{
    "metadata": [
        "count": <count of entities>
    ],
    "debug": [
        <debug messages>
    ],
    "results": [
        <List of results>
    ],
    "errors": [
        <List of errors>
    ]
}
```

Is there any better design or blueprint for returning the response JSON

Comment: Follow This :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806386/standard-json-api-response-format

Comment: Not a valid json

Comment: Google JSON guide seems simpler https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml