# Recommandation for the response payload body of a collection resource

Tags: json, http, response, content-type, payload

Is there any recommendation or standard for the payload body of an HTTP response to an HTTP GET request on a *collection* resource? I cannot find anything in the [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) family.

The [Representational state transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Relationship_between_URI_and_HTTP_methods) article on Wikipedia states:

> For a collection resource, such as https://api.example.com/collection/, GET retrieves the URIs of the member resources of the collection resource in the response body.

But there is no reference.

With the `application/json` media type, I have seen sometimes an array of URIs in the response, for instance:

```
["/collection/item1", "/collection/item2", (…), "/collection/itemN"]
```

I have also seen objects with `"links"` keys instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would answer that : prefer light response to have better performance ! No need to add a (useless) key like "link" or "links" if your endpoint is something like this => "[GET] https://[your domain]/links" - This way, it seems obvious that you will get a link list response.
Lot of libraries use same response syntax like this => response.data.items - by this way, you will be able to refactor your code to industrialize the response retrieval.

Comment: I would like to use a standard JSON format for this, not a home made JSON format. That way the server can evolve independently without breaking clients, as they would rely on the interface provided by the standard JSON format.

Comment: So, look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806386/standard-json-api-response-format