# How to get this response JSON structure with Rocket (Rust)

Tags: json, rust, rust-rocket

I have a simple web service that I'm writing with Rocket, whenever `data` comes as a 200 response, it contains a vector of `String`s. When an error comes, I want to have custom errors. And the structure I want to impose on those responses should be like in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23708903/4402306 , specifically:

for successful responses:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "topics": ["topic1", "topic2", ...]
  }
}
```

and for errors:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "status_code": 404,
    "message": "not found (or any other custom error)"
  }
}
```

For the errors I have the confusion of using a `catcher` in rocket vs implementing my own error structures like an enum (with rocket derivations):

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Responder)]
#[response(content_type = "json")]
pub enum APIError{
  CustomError1(String, #[response(ignore)] String),
  CustomError2(String, #[response(ignore)] String),
  ...
}
```

So what should I use to achieve my goal?

I also not sure how to represent the successful case (because with `rocket`, the first field should implement the `Responder` trait, but I have a `Vec<String>` there)

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Responder)]
#[response(content_type = "json")]
pub struct Data {
  topics: Vec<String>,
}
```

And finally, I think I also need to combine `Data` and `APIError` in a single `Response` struct - but then it's not clear to me how to control when to return what.

Assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: are u using EventsStream?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a custom `Catcher` that returns a custom message.
See [this](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/struct.Catcher.html).