# Standard Json Reply from an API Call

Tags: javascript, json, reply

I am having argument with a friend here we are working on a project together. I am handling the front end and he is doing the backend API. I told him to return pure Json text in his reply to the API call. But instead, he replied with something like below:

```
callBackFunction({"sample": "value"});
```

I told him, it is supposed to be only

```
{"sample": "value"}
```

But he insisted that his way is the STANDARD JSON REPLY. We are still arguing about this till today.

For now, I manually trim the extra texts just to get the Json, it works OK, but trimming texts and characters is so dangerous, prone to error etc. So, I want to ask all programmers in the world, is the callBackFunction() is part of the standard JSON reply???? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: `callBackFunction({"sample": "value"});` is clearly not valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks @CameronSkinner that's what I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered here [Is there any standard for JSON API response format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806386/is-there-any-standard-for-json-api-response-format). But yes
`{"sample": "value"}` would be considered the standard way to receive JSON